# Как лучше всего проверить что в массиве нет элементов?

Tags: php, массивы

Какой из вариантов наиболее корректный, для проверки php массива на отсутствие в нём элементов?

1. `if ($arr) {...}`
2. `if (empty($arr)) {...}`
3. `if (isset($arr[0])) {...}`
4. `if (count($arr)) {...}`

Comment: Второй еще проверяет сам массив на существование, в отличие от остальных. То есть если заранее известно что массив есть, то эта проверка избыточна

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Да все, в общем, корректны. Только в первом и четвертом случаях будет преобразование типа к bool, а третий подойдет только для индексных массивов. Есть еще вариант `sizeof($arr)`.

Comment: ТРЕТИЙ - НЕ КОРРЕКТНЫЙ. Например, $a = [NULL];  - не пустой массив.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, наилучший вариант `if ($arr === Array()) {...}`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 2):

**ОТВЕТ**:

Проверять пуст массив через функции count и sizeof - не стоит, так как он тратить время на обработку. мизерное время, но тратит.

Лучшие варианты это:

```
1. if($arr) {...} // Проверит на наличие элементов внутри
2. if(empty( $arr )) {...} // Проверит существование переменной с массивом и наличие элементов внутри
3. if(array_shift( $arr )) {...} // Проверит наличие первого элемента
4. if($arr[0]) {...} // Проверит на наличие нулевого элемента, для индексного массива, который начинается с 0
```

**ИССЛЕДОВАНИЯ:**

1. Данные ответ проверен через микротест со сложным массивом, с 40014 элементов и PHP 7.1
2. Исполнение скрипта происходило на локальной машине (Open Server 5.2).
3. Замер происходил через функцию php microtime()
4. Результат проверялся трижды

**РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ ИССЛЕДОВАНИЙ:**

> Первый запуск

1. if(count($arr)) {...} : 0.0010001659393311 сек.
2. if(sizeof($arr)) {...} : 0 сек.
3. if($array) {...} : 0 сек.
4. if(empty($arr)) {...} : 0 сек.
5. if(array_shift($arr)) {...} : 0 сек.
6. if($arr[0]) {...} : 0 сек.

> Второй запуск

1. if(count($arr)) {...} : 0 сек.
2. if(sizeof($arr)) {...} : 0.0010011196136475 сек.
3. if($array) {...} : 0 сек.
4. if(empty($arr)) {...} : 0 сек.
5. if(array_shift($arr)) {...} : 0 сек.
6. if($arr[0]) {...} : 0 сек.

> Третий запуск

1. if(count($arr)) {...} : 0.00099992752075195 сек.
2. if(sizeof($arr)) {...} : 0 сек.
3. if($array) {...} : 0 сек.
4. if(empty($arr)) {...} : 0 сек.
5. if(array_shift($arr)) {...} : 0 сек.
6. if($arr[0]) {...} : 0 сек.

**ЧТО Я ЮЗАЮ:**

Для себя использую if($arr) {...} и if($arr[0]) {...}, так как нет необходимости вызывать дополнительные функции - обертки

Comment: П.3 какая-то бессмыслица

Comment: П.4 тоже бессмыслица. проверяет не наличие элемента, а его пустоту. [0] при такой проверке вернет что массив не имеет элементов

Answer (score 1):

if($array === []){
...
}

Более оптимальный так как:

- Код более читаемый - "Если переменная равна пустому массиву";
- Сразу идет контроль типов, и вы действительно сравниваете массив;
- Не используются функции, а только сравнение, значит этот код будет работать немного быстрее;

Answer (score 0):

В документации сказано, что **массив без элементов** интерпретируется как **false**.
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

```
var_dump((bool) array(12)); // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) array());   // bool(false)
```

Вот я и убедился, что самый быстрый способ

```
if ( $arr ) {}
```

```php
$arr = [];
$a1000 = range(0, 1000); // 0,1,2...1000

for( $i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    $j = rand(0,20);
    if ( $j === 0 ) {
        $arr[] = [];
    } else {
        shuffle( $a1000 );
        $arr[] = array_slice($a1000,0,$j);
    }
}
$t = microtime( true );
$n = count_not_empty1( $arr );
$t = microtime(true) - $t;
echo 'if ( $a ): N='.$n.' T='.round($t*1000,4).' ms'.PHP_EOL;

$t = microtime( true );
$n = count_not_empty2( $arr );
$t = microtime(true) - $t;
echo 'if ( $a !== [] ): N='.$n.' T='.round($t*1000,4).' ms'.PHP_EOL;

$t = microtime( true );
$n = count_not_empty3( $arr );
$t = microtime(true) - $t;
echo 'if ( !empty($a) ): N='.$n.' T='.round($t*1000,4).' ms'.PHP_EOL;

$t = microtime( true );
$n = count_not_empty4( $arr );
$t = microtime(true) - $t;
echo 'if ( count($a) ): N='.$n.' T='.round($t*1000,4).' ms'.PHP_EOL;




function count_not_empty1( &$arr )
{
    $n = 0;
    for( $i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++ ) {
        if ( $arr[$i] ) {
            $n++;
        }
    }
    return $n;
}
function count_not_empty2( &$arr )
{
    $n = 0;
    for( $i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++ ) {
        if ( $arr[$i] !== [] ) {
            $n++;
        }
    }
    return $n;
}
function count_not_empty3( &$arr )
{
    $n = 0;
    for( $i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++ ) {
        if ( !empty($arr[$i]) ) {
            $n++;
        }
    }
    return $n;
}
function count_not_empty4( &$arr )
{
    $n = 0;
    for( $i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++ ) {
        if ( count($arr[$i]) ) {
            $n++;
        }
    }
    return $n;
}
```

```html
if ( $a ): N=952522 T=117.7402 ms
if ( $a !== [] ): N=952522 T=122.844 ms
if ( !empty($a) ): N=952522 T=125.299 ms
if ( count($a) ): N=952522 T=128.9139 ms
```

Answer (score -1):

Я использую `if((bool) array_filter($array))`

Comment: Для своих задач хорошый способ. Но это уже не проверка массива на пустоту